# JQueryUI sortable thead and tbody shrinked while dragging row with two fields hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, draggable

I have a table with different rows and fields. In one row I have two fields with `display:none;` and when I make the drag of this rows, there is an effect like lateral padding in the `<tbody>` and the `<thead>`, the table isn't shrinked, elements of the table yes.

In the next JsFiddle in the first row doesn't work correctly, but in second row which only have one field with `display:none;` it works.

If have any question ask it.

**Errors example**
[image]

**Table while dragging:**

[image]

At first I thought it could be solved by looking for the number of `<td>` elements with the class `.hidden-td` (class that has a `display: none;`) and look for the element with the class `.placeholder-style` (is the class that has the `<tr>` that is generated when doing the drag) and add many `<td>` as there are in the `<tr>` that I am moving, but not, isn't working.

I know how much fields have clase `.hidden-td` with this line

`var numcells = $('.hidden-td').length;`

**Problem**

I have 9 elements in the first row and in the other I have 8. In my function `start()` I only hidden one column in my placeholder so when I make the drag of the first row there's one column left without apply the class `.hidden-td` and that's why there's a space at the end of the columns.

How can I fix this?

https://jsfiddle.net/w52m5ggb/20/

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39171688/jquery-ui-sortable-table-and-cell-is-shrinking-while-dragging-tr does this solve your problem?

Comment: In the JsFiddle fix the problem but not in real code, see the example I will attach in question.

Comment: I think I know why don't work in my real code seems it's cause I have two fields, if have two fields with `display:none;` it's not working. https://jsfiddle.net/w52m5ggb/19/

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is exactly... the fiddle works ok?

Comment: I will modify the question to make it easier, give me a few minuts @ProEvilz thanks

Comment: I understand now. Its because it's a table. Place a div inside the tbody and set the height on that rather than the tbody it's self. Or to make it even easier, just use a grid system instead of a table

Comment: I don't think it's because it's a table, you can try the JsFiddle removing the first row and will work perfectly. Can you modify and make an other update on the JsFiddle with you idea and then test it? @ProEvilz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having struggled with the sortable plugin myself for the past few days, I think the following changes need to be done:

1. Add the helper function to create the correct sizes on the helper (draggable object) to have the correct size.
2. In the start function, add the item html to the placeholder html, to have the placeholder stay identical to the original.

Code:

```
$("#tbodyproject").sortable({
    items: "> tr",
    appendTo: "parent",
    helper: "clone",
    placeholder: "placeholder-style",
    start: function(event, ui) {
      $(this).find('.placeholder-style td:nth-child(2)').addClass('hidden-td')

      //copy item html to placeholder html

      ui.placeholder.html(ui.item.html());

      //hide the items but keep the height/width. 
      ui.placeholder.css('visibility', 'hidden');
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        ui.item.css('display', '')
    },

    //add helper function to keep draggable object the same width
    helper: function(e, tr)
    {
        var $originals = tr.children();
        var $helper = tr.clone();
        $helper.children().each(function(index)
        {
        // Set helper cell sizes to match the original sizes
        $(this).width($originals.eq(index).width());
        });
        return $helper;
    },
    update: function( event, ui ) {
        let newOrder = $(this).sortable('toArray');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:'/admin/projects/updateOrder',
            data: {ids: newOrder}
        })
       .done(function( msg ) {
        location.reload();        
       });
    }
}).disableSelection();
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w52m5ggb/24/)

Answer (score 0):

When the **placeholder** is created, it  only takes the number of cell in the row and create an empty row with those cells.

You are adding class `hidden-td` to nth child 2, so you are hiding one cell. This is OK for rows 2 and up, but not for first row, since you have one more cell in that row. See **placeholder** for row 2:

```
<td colspan="1">&nbsp;</td><td colspan="1" class="hidden-td">&nbsp;</td><td colspan="1">&nbsp;</td><td colspan="1">&nbsp;</td><td colspan="1">&nbsp;</td><td colspan="1">&nbsp;</td><td colspan="1">&nbsp;</td><td colspan="1">&nbsp;</td>
```

For first row:

```
<td colspan="1">&nbsp;</td><td colspan="1" class="hidden-td">&nbsp;</td><td colspan="1">&nbsp;</td><td colspan="1">&nbsp;</td><td colspan="1">&nbsp;</td><td colspan="1">&nbsp;</td><td colspan="1">&nbsp;</td><td colspan="1">&nbsp;</td><td colspan="1">&nbsp;</td>
```

What you can do is hide every cell in the placeholder and show only the number you need. This can be done with CSS, like this:

```
.placeholder-style td {
  display: none;
}

.placeholder-style td:nth-child(-n+7) {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

Result: https://jsfiddle.net/3g3bt80e/1/

Comment: I like the way you do it but there is a problem. Check this version https://jsfiddle.net/3g3bt80e/2/ I added some css more, like I have in my real code.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the approach in the snippet below.

```js
$("#tabs").tabs();

$("#tbodyproject").sortable({
    items: "> tr",
    appendTo: "parent",
    helper: "clone",
    placeholder: "placeholder-style",
    start: function(event, ui) {
      ui.helper.css('display', 'table');
     // console.log(ui.placeholder.html())
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        ui.item.css('display', '')
    },
    update: function( event, ui ) {
        let newOrder = $(this).sortable('toArray');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:'/admin/projects/updateOrder',
            data: {ids: newOrder}
        })
       .done(function( msg ) {
        location.reload();        
       });
    }
}).disableSelection();
```

```css
img {
  width: 100px;
}
.hidden-td{
  display:none;
}
.table{
  background-color:green;
  border:0;
  width:100%;
}
.trdrag{
  background-color:yellow;
}
.trdrag.ui-sortable-handle td.tdslug, .trdrag.ui-sortable-handle td.tdslug img{
  text-align:center;
  align-items:center;
  display: table-cell;
  justify-content: center;
}
.trdrag.ui-sortable-handle td.tdslug{
  white-space:normal;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
.trdrag.ui-sortable-handle td.tdslug img{
  padding-left:1rem;
}
.trdrag.ui-sortable-handle {
  text-align:center;
  align-items:center;
  display: table-row;
  justify-content: center;
  width:100%;
  margin-left: .3rem;
}
  
.thcenter{
  background-color:grey !important;
}
.ui-sortable-helper {
  left:0px!important;
}
.idrow{
  width:5%;
}
.tdvisible{
  width:5%;
}
.tdslug{
  width:10%;
}
.tdimg{
  width:15%;
}
.tdorder{
  width:20%;
}
.tdacciones{
  width:40%;
}

.placeholder-style td {
  display: none;
}

.placeholder-style td:nth-child(-n+7) {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="tabs">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div id="table1">
              <table class="table">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th class="thcenter">ID</th>
                    <th class="thcenter">Visible</th>
                    <th class="thcenter">Nombre</th>
                    <th class="thcenter">Header</th>
                    <th class="thcenter">Home</th>
                    <th class="thcenter">Orden</th>
                    <th class="thcenter"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span>Acciones</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="tbodyproject"> 
                    <tr id="id1" class="trdrag">
                      <td class="idrow tdcenter"><p id="margindata">1</p></td>
                      <td  class="hidden-td" style="display:none;">Testing</td>
                      <td  class="hidden-td" style="display:none;">Testing2</td>
                      <td class="tdcenter tdvisible"> 
                        Yes
                      </td>
                      <td class="tdslug"><p id="margindata">Slug</p></td>
                      <td class="tdimg"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="sizeheader"></td>
                      <td class="tdimg"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="sizehome"></td>
                      <td class="tdcenter tdorder"><p id="margindata">Order 1</p></td>
                      <td class="tdacciones">
                      <form method="POST" action="{{route('admin.projects.destroy',$project->id)}}" onsubmit="return ConfirmarBorrar()">
                          <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" id="margindata">Edit</a> 
                          <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="margindata">
                          <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="Token 1">Delete
                      </form>
                     </td>
                    </tr>
                     <tr id="id1" class="trdrag">
                      <td class="idrow tdcenter"><p id="margindata">2</p></td>
                      <td style="display:none;">Testing</td>
                      <td class="tdcenter tdvisible"> 
                        Yes
                      </td>
                      <td class="tdslug"><p id="margindata">Slug</p></td>
                      <td class="tdimg"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="sizeheader"></td>
                      <td class="tdimg"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="sizehome"></td>
                      <td class="tdcenter tdorder"><p id="margindata">Order 1</p></td>
                      <td class="tdacciones">
                      <form method="POST" action="{{route('admin.projects.destroy',$project->id)}}" onsubmit="return ConfirmarBorrar()">
                          <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" id="margindata">Edit</a> 
                          <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="margindata">
                          <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="Token 1">Delete
                      </form>
                     </td>
                    </tr>
                     <tr id="id1" class="trdrag">
                      <td class="idrow tdcenter"><p id="margindata">3</p></td>
                      <td style="display:none;">Testing</td>
                      <td class="tdcenter tdvisible"> 
                        Yes
                      </td>
                      <td class="tdslug"><p id="margindata">Slug</p></td>
                      <td class="tdimg"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="sizeheader"></td>
                      <td class="tdimg"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="sizehome"></td>
                      <td class="tdcenter tdorder"><p id="margindata">Order 1</p></td>
                      <td class="tdacciones">
                      <form method="POST" action="{{route('admin.projects.destroy',$project->id)}}" onsubmit="return ConfirmarBorrar()">
                          <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" id="margindata">Edit</a> 
                          <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="margindata">
                          <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="Token 1">Delete
                      </form>
                     </td>
                    </tr>
                     <tr id="id1" class="trdrag">
                      <td class="idrow tdcenter"><p id="margindata">1</p></td>
                      <td style="display:none;">Testing</td>
                      <td class="tdcenter tdvisible"> 
                        Yes
                      </td>
                      <td class="tdslug"><p id="margindata">Slug</p></td>
                      <td class="tdimg"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="sizeheader"></td>
                      <td class="tdimg"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="sizehome"></td>
                      <td class="tdcenter tdorder"><p id="margindata">Order 1</p></td>
                      <td class="tdacciones">
                      <form method="POST" action="{{route('admin.projects.destroy',$project->id)}}" onsubmit="return ConfirmarBorrar()">
                          <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" id="margindata">Edit</a> 
                          <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="margindata">
                          <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="Token 1">Delete
                      </form>
                     </td>
                    </tr>
                     <tr id="id1" class="trdrag">
                      <td class="idrow tdcenter"><p id="margindata">4</p></td>
                      <td style="display:none;">Testing</td>
                      <td class="tdcenter tdvisible"> 
                        Yes
                      </td>
                      <td class="tdslug"><p id="margindata">Slug</p></td>
                      <td class="tdimg"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="sizeheader"></td>
                      <td class="tdimg"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="sizehome"></td>
                      <td class="tdcenter tdorder"><p id="margindata">Order 1</p></td>
                      <td class="tdacciones">
                      <form method="POST" action="{{route('admin.projects.destroy',$project->id)}}" onsubmit="return ConfirmarBorrar()">
                          <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" id="margindata">Edit</a> 
                          <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="margindata">
                          <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="Token 1">Delete
                      </form>
                     </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="id2" class="trdrag">
                      <td class="idrow tdcenter"><p id="margindata">5</p></td>
                      <td class="tdcenter tdvisible"> 
                        Yes
                      </td>
                      <td class="tdslug"><p id="margindata">Slug</p></td>
                      <td class="tdimg"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="sizeheader"></td>
                      <td class="tdimg"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="sizehome"></td>
                      <td class="tdcenter tdorder"><p id="margindata">Order 2</p></td>
                      <td class="tdacciones">
                      <form method="POST" action="{{route('admin.projects.destroy',$project->id)}}" onsubmit="return ConfirmarBorrar()">

                          <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" id="margindata">Edit</a> 
                          <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="margindata">
                          <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="Token 2">Delete
                      </form>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
              <br><br>
            </div>
        </div>
```