# jQuery: Adding td elements with one class to tr

Tags: javascript, jquery

First of all I have to find the number of cells with one class, this line works.

```
var numcells = $('.hidden-td').length
```

And now I have to find the element with the class `.placeholder-style` I use this line (only one `<tr>`have this class):

```
$(this).find('.placeholder-style')
```

Now I have to add the same number of `var numcells`like `<td>`inside the `<tr>`with the clase `.hidden-td` I think this will be with `.addClass('hidden-td')`.

How can I make this?

Thanks

Comment: What have you actually tried so far? I think you've misunderstood the concept of `addClass()`. This method just adds a class on to an existing element. Perhaps look at the jQuery documentation for `append()` - http://api.jquery.com/append/

Comment: *I think this will be with .addClass('hidden-td')*  On which element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming this is the correct structure you're after... if not, post your HTML so I can amend it but either way, this is how you should do it.

```
var numcells = $('.hidden-td').length;

var content = $(this).find('.placeholder-style');

for (i = 0; i < numcells; i++) { 
    content.append('<td class="hidden-td"></td>');
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly I think this will make the problem works but not. The real problem is this: ons/47329008/jqueryui-sortable-thead-and-tbody-shrinked-while-dragging-tr maybe you can check it.

Comment: Link is wrong sorry check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47329008/jqueryui-sortable-thead-and-tbody-shrinked-while-dragging-tr

Comment: Please accept the answer, I'll take a look at your other one soon

Comment: Done @ProEvilz thanks for you help and hope you can help me too in other question

Comment: let me ask you something which have relation with this question. In the blade I have a foreach, so it's not correctly this line `var numcells = $('.hidden-td').length;` cause it gets the class of all rows. How can I fix to take it only all of one row?

Comment: I'm sorry, but what you're saying doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Let me try to explain it again. I have a table which a foreach (to make the rows with the columns). Each row have some fields with the class `.hidden-td` , if I have for example 20 rows, and each row have 3fields with the class `.hidden-td` I will get with this line `var numcells = $('.hidden-td').length;` 60. And I only need to know how many `.hidden-td` fields I have in the row with class `.placeholder-style`.