# Javascript: Correct syntax in for

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```
$(this).find('.placeholder-style td:nth-child(1)').addClass('hidden-td')
$(this).find('.placeholder-style td:nth-child(2)').addClass('hidden-td')
$(this).find('.placeholder-style td:nth-child(3)').addClass('hidden-td')
$(this).find('.placeholder-style td:nth-child(4)').addClass('hidden-td')
$(this).find('.placeholder-style td:nth-child(5)').addClass('hidden-td')
```

And I want to do it dynamic like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++){
   $(this).find('.placeholder-style td:nth-child'.(i)).addClass('hidden-td')
}
```

Which is the correct syntax to this code?

Comment: Just change the starting value to `1` instead of `0` and use `<=` instead of `<`.  And use string concatenation (as indicated by Teemu below). And don't forget to use `var i`.

Comment: Where is the `foreach`?

Comment: `+` operator has used to be a string concatenation operator in JS ...

Comment: Most jQuery methods implicitly iterate over the collection, so I'd rather try to narrow down the matches, then call addClass once on the right set of elements, e.g. `$(this).find('.placeholder-style td').filter( function(idx){ return idx < 5 }).addClass('hidden-td')`

Answer (score 3):

1. In JavaScript, the concatenation operator is `+` not `.`
2. The `(` and `)` are part of the selector syntax, not JavaScript syntax, they need to be **strings**.

Such

```
$(this).find(
    '.placeholder-style td:nth-child(' + i + ')' 
).addClass('hidden-td')
```

This would probably be easier to do without the for loop.

```
$(this).find(
    '.placeholder-style td:not(:nth-child(6) ~ td)' 
).addClass('hidden-td')
```

Comment: @LluísPuigFerrer — The loop should be exactly as it is in the question. http://jsbin.com/masuvuluvi/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: Thanks @Quentin for you answer and explanation. Your jsbin works, I'm checking in my real code and is not working. I will put here a link to my other question and maybe you can help me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47329008/jqueryui-sortable-thead-and-tbody-shrinked-while-dragging-row-with-two-fields-hi?noredirect=1#comment81656767_47329008

Comment: With your second answer works, but not with for. Can check it?

Comment: I know why is not working. I'm using in for a variable which I get like this: `        var numcells = $('.hidden-td').length
` but in blade I have a `foreach` so I get all the `.hidden-td` of blade not in the row. Know how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

- Should define `i`  variable  like `var i`
- The `i` value should be start with 1
- use `+` instead of `.` for concatenate  string

just like,

```
for ( var i = 1; i <= 5; i++){
   $(this).find('.placeholder-style td:nth-child'+i).addClass('hidden-td')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think u can do this in easier way

`.placeholder-style td:nth-child(-n+5){display: none;}`